# Count programs running by it's className

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to detect **how many instances of a application person is running**. Did he open my application once? Twice? Thrice?
I tried to detect it by checking it's instances by process names, but in windows it is pointles - people might change .exe name and it won't count towards final number.

How would I proceed then? I thought about searching it by className (HWND?) rather by processName, but how would I do it?

This is the code I am using for detecting by process name:

```
int Platform::getMulticlientCount(const std::string& ProcessName)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32 = { sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32) };
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    const char *cstr = ProcessName.c_str();
    int counter = 0;
    if (Process32First(hSnapshot, &pe32))
    {
        do
        {
            if (_tcsicmp(pe32.szExeFile, cstr) == 0)
            {
                counter++;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe32));
    }

    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: "*I thought about searching it by className (HWND?) rather by processName, but how would I do it?*" - look at `FindWindow/Ex()`, or `EnumWindows()` with `GetClassName()`

Comment: Since this is your application, why don't you increment a counter on startup, and decrement it on application exit? You'll have to keep that counter in a shared memory region, e.g. a memory mapped file. Or use a [semaphore object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/semaphore-objects) as a quick and dirty way to monitor global state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance of the Remy:

```
static int counter;
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{

    char classname[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    GetClassNameA(hwnd,classname, MAX_PATH);
    if (_tcsicmp(classname, (char*)lParam) == 0)
        counter++;
    return true;
}
int Platform::getMulticlientCount(const std::string& ClassName)
{
    counter = 0;
    const char *cstr = ClassName.c_str();
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)cstr);
    return counter;
}
```

If you also need to get the instance, in `EnumWindowsProc`:

```
HINSTANCE instance = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE);
```

If you also need to get the processId, in `EnumWindowsProc`:

```
DWORD pid;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code that counts the instances that are running. While the application count the instances it self it does not matter if the binary is renamed. I used a file to keep the example simple but registry would work too. The only thing that is missing is a global mutex to protect the file against concurrent access. HTH

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>

#include <Windows.h>

class GlobalCounter
{
public:
    GlobalCounter(const std::string& id)
    : _id(id)
    {
        const auto filename = "C:\\users\\twollgam\\" + id + ".counter";

        if (GlobalFindAtomA(id.c_str()) == 0)
        {
            std::ofstream(filename) << 1;

            std::cout << "I am the first instance." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            auto counter = 0;

            std::ifstream(filename) >> counter;

            ++counter;

            std::ofstream(filename) << counter;

            std::cout << "I am the " << counter << " instance." << std::endl;
        }

        _atom = GlobalAddAtomA(id.c_str());
    }

    ~GlobalCounter()
    {
        const auto filename = "C:\\users\\twollgam\\" + _id + ".counter";
        auto counter = 0;

        std::ifstream(filename) >> counter;

        --counter;

        std::ofstream(filename) << counter;

        GlobalDeleteAtom(_atom);
    }

private:
    const std::string _id;
    ATOM _atom;
};

int main()
{
    const auto globalCounter = GlobalCounter("test");

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(30));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This fails in case the application terminates without running destructors (e.g. when crashing). Unlike handles to kernel objects, the reference count of a string in the global atom table doesn't get automatically released by the OS. And since you are using the global atom table, you should *really* make sure to use a unique name (e.g. the string representation of a GUID).